# Archive not sorting correctly

Tags: custom-post-types, archives, order

I have a custom post type called "cif-events" and I want to sort by the value in wpcf-start-time. I added the following to my functions.php:

```
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'set_order_for_archives');

function set_order_for_archives($q) {
  if ($q->is_post_type_archive('cif-groups')) {
    $q->set('orderby', 'title');
    $q->set('order', 'ASC');
    $q->set('posts_per_page', 300);
  } elseif ($q->is_post_type_archive('cif-events')) {
    $q->set('orderby', 'wpcf-start-time');
    $q->set('order', 'ASC');
    $q->set('posts_per_page', 300);
  } elseif ($q->is_post_type_archive('cif-venues')) {
    $q->set('orderby', 'title');
    $q->set('order', 'ASC');
    $q->set('posts_per_page', 300);
  }
  return $q;
}
```

It is not sorting correctly, however. It's sorting by post-date I think instead. post-per-page does seem to be set correctly though.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the [`orderby` parameters for `WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters) to see all of the valid values that can be.

If `wpcf-start-time` is a meta key, then `orderby` should be `meta_value`, which will also require you set a `meta_key` argument to tell WP what meta key you want to order on-

```
} elseif ($q->is_post_type_archive('cif-events')) {
    $q->set('orderby', 'meta_value');
    $q->set('meta_key', 'wpcf-start-time');
    $q->set('order', 'ASC');
    $q->set('posts_per_page', 300);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per [Order & Orderby Parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters) `orderby` doesn't just accept key name.

You need to set `orderby` to `'meta_value'` string and `meta_key` to key name.